# Is it possible to cache a variable from a action after html.erb renders for css.erb? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have this action

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  ...
  def results
    @users = User.search(params[:name], params[:gender])
    render 'user_results'
  end
  ...
```

The problem is rails is running back through this code again for when it renders my `user_results.css.erb` which is giving unsuspecting results as the params appear not to be available and I dont want to run back through the code again anyway.

I tried to cache the `@users` variable by doing `@users ||= User.search(params...` but it runs back through the code anyway and my `search` method which is giving different results than when it first runs through for the `user_results.html.erb` when the params are available.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you running this code from `user_results.css.erb` at all? Is it necessary? Because this is a code smell to me. If you need to render custom CSS here then simply use a separate action, don't call it `results` call it `user_results` and the two calls will be separate.

The thing to remember is that there are actually 2 different web requests, one to the HTML and one to the CSS. They could be called individually in some cases, not necessarily tied together for all browsers, and that is why this is a code smell to me is you're blurring the lines between the two in your controller.

For more clarity, try adding this to your method:

```
logger.info "#{request.format}"
```

You could also enable/disable things based on the format:

```
if request.format.html?
```

If you are doing something like assigning a different color to each user in your CSS, then I would just move that into your HTML as an inline `<style>` block, and then you won't need any sort of caching. I'm 99% sure caching is not the right thing here.

Comment: I am using the @users variable in the css.erb file to give individual user based css ie  `<% @users.each do |user| %>` then list the user style attributes I have saved.

Comment: So essentually your saying the browser will recieve the html template first then make another request for the stylesheet? I think I get what your saying now.